# How to get different images to display in a jQuery slider plugin for different screen sizes?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to get my jQuery slider plugin to show portrait images for mobile and iPad devices, and landscape images for large screen devices. However, I am not succeeding. I have tried several strategies, however none have worked. If you know how to do this, your help would be much appreciated.

HTML

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="slider" class="nivoSlider">

        <img src="../Images/islal11.JPG" data-thumb="../Images/islal11.JPG"  alt="Little girl wearing Tomatis headphones"  class="image large"/>
        <img src="../Images/bellal12.jpg" data-thumb="../Images/bellal12.jpg"  alt="Girl with Tomatis headphones two"  class="image large"/>
        <img src="../Images/islal12.JPG" data-thumb="../Images/islal12.JPG"  alt="Little girl wearing Tomatis headphones 2"  class="image large"/>

        <img src="../Images/bellap11.JPG" data-thumb="../Images/bellap11.JPG" alt="Girl with Tomatatis headphones" class="image small"/>
        <img src="../Images/islap11.JPG" data-thumb="../Images/islap11.JPG"  alt="Little girl wearing Tomatis headphones"  class="image small"/>
        <img src="../Images/islap12.jpg" data-thumb="../Images/islap12.jpg"   alt="Girl with Tomatis headphones two"  class="image small"/>

    </div> <!--closing slide div-->
</div><!--closing container div-->
```

Answer (score 0):

Give you're #slider id a max-width inside you're css.

```
#slider{
    max-width: 640px;
}
```

you can give a max-width or max-heigth based on mobile size with @media:
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp

I hope that this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

```
#slider .large {
    display: none;
}


@media (min-width: 640px) {

   #slider .small {
       display: none;
   }

}
```

If you really need to delete the images to the slider work properly you can use jQuery

```
if( window.innerWidth < 650) { //if less than 650px remove large images
    $('.#slider img.large').remove();
} else { //if equal or more than 650px remove small images
    $('.#slider img.small').remove();
}
```

Make sure to call this before trigger the slider.

Comment: Thank you for your help it is much appreciated.